# Oauth2 - Requesting access to a specific subset of resources

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I am developing an Restful API for client applications which will reach to the resources on the server after the resource owner gives necessary permissions. For achieving this, I am planning to use Spring Oauth2. Currently, I am asking for an auth. code to the auth. server and using it to get a token for reaching the resources of the resource owner. For instance:

1- The client application asks for the scope 'readPhotos' which is mapped to: /api/v1/photos

2- The resource owner enters his credentials on the page that the authorization server shows.

3- Authorization server asks the resource owner if he wants to grant access for his photos.

4- Resource owner approves and authorization code is passed to the client application.

5- After retrieving the code, the client app passes it to the auth. server for the token.

6- Token is received and the client can reach the photos.

However, I want to let the client to specify the subset of resources it wants to ask permission for. For example, lets say the resource owner has "photo1", "photo2", "photo3", "photo4" in the resource server. What is the correct way to make the client application to ask authorization for a subset of resources, such as files "photo1, photo3" but not the whole collection. How to make scope definitions? As the resources will vary for each user (the photo ids will be different for each user), it is not possible to define each resource with a single scope statically using ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter of Spring Oauth2. Currently I am using the following configuration for photo permissions. However, as I mentioned this scope definition is too generic and gives permission for the whole set.

```
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

http.requestMatchers().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/photos").access(" #oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and #oauth2.hasScope('readPhotos')")
```

Answer (score 0):

The access token has scopes and it has an audience (generally speaking). Those are your variables. You would probably have to use scopes that correspond to the resources (but I supppose audience is sort of relevant as well). The tough part is validating the scopes (or audiences) in the Auth server. Really, I wouldn't expect an auth server to be able to know anything about the available resources, so you pretty much have to grant any scope that a client requests, which may defeat the object. So I think the bottom line is you need to ask yourself if the token is really the right place to put that information, unless your example wasn't really realistic, and the real use case is more interesting.

Or you could put the onus of validating the scopes on the user (he has to approve access to individual photos). That works, I guess, for a grant with approvals (e.g. auth code).

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the reply. I realized that the question was not 100% clear. I fixed the first post. The client redirects the resource owner to auth. server. The res. owner enters his credentials. If correct, server asks the owner for confirmation. If approved, code is sent to the client app and used for getting token... My question is more like how to define the scopes so each individual resource (photo) can be requested by the client, and authorized by owner. The auth server should ask the owner as "Want to grant access for photos 1 and 3?". How to represent each resource with a scope?

Comment: A scope is just a string. You can call it "photo1" if you want to. Just redirect to the auth server with a new scope name every time you need authorization.

Comment: Ok, but how the auth. server will create a code/token that gives access to that the specific resource "photo1" but not others. In the ResourceServerConfiguration class, the scope mappings are done as 
`http.requestMatchers().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/photos")`
And I map it to the scope name: readPhotos with
`.access("#oauth2.hasScope('readPhotos'))`
So, the auth. server knows to give only GET permission to the resource at that URI. Since it's impossible to define each single resource in this configuration class, how to do this dynamically?

Comment: The client application should get the list of photos from the resource server with the first token, using /api/v1/user/{userid}/photos (same problem here since we can't define every user in the system in the config file statically).  Then by using the result to ask authorization for specific photos (1 and 3). (Second token).